# How to give name the rows and columns of a matrix in Matlab 2015b?

Tags: matlab, format

I have the following problem with Matlab version 2015b: I got a matrix A and two vectors B and N ( with fitting dimenstion and consisting of integer entries). I want to use make a table in the form of sketch below (where "z" is just the letter z). I guess it would be easiest to use the array2table function, I just can not make it work. Here is an example for A, B, and N:

```
N = [ 3; 1; 0; 3 ];
B = [ 2; 4; 3; 5; 1; 2 ];
A = [ 2, -1, 1, 5; 
      -1, 3, 1, -1;
      -4, 1, -2, 6;
      2, 2, -1, 3;
      -1, -1, 1, -1;
      -2, 3, -1, 1 ];
```

Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: Table column names cannot be numbers in 15b, they must be valid matlab variable names

Comment: @Wolfie: Thanks for your answer. And if instead of numerical values we use for example B_1,B_2,... so valid variable names, would this work?

Comment: Sure, just `array2table( A, 'VariableNames', N, 'RowNames', B )` where `N` and `B` have to be cellstr variables with valid names. Read the documentation for this function...